# Trouble with OnLoad Sub (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, function, onload

I have some trouble with declaring a default path file on startup. 
Everytime I run the program, it's saying that pathFile is null.
Does someone know what I need to change in my code?

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Public Class GlobalVariables
    Public Shared pathFile As String
End Class

Public Class Form1
    Protected Overridable Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
        GlobalVariables.pathFile = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        ' create or overwrite the file
        Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(GlobalVariables.pathFile)

        ' add text to file
        Dim info As Byte() = New UTF8Encoding(True).GetBytes(rtbText.Text)
        fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length)
        fs.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks in advance! 
- Xaaf Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to override `OnLoad` (which would be `Overrides` instead of `Overridable`), I would handle the load event:

```
Private Sub Form_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    GlobalVariables.pathFile = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop
End Sub
```

You could probably just set the value where `pathFile` is declared instead:

```
Public Class GlobalVariables
    Public Shared pathFile As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop
End Class
```

Comment: I get an error saying that the access to the path is denied.
This is at the `Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(GlobalVariables.pathFile)`

Comment: @XaafCode Well, that's not really related to your question, but [`File.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx) "creates or overwrites a file in the specified path", and the path you are specifying is your desktop directory which is not a file and already exists, so getting access denied is probably a good thing! :-)

Comment: Oh, thank you! Wasn't really thinking about that! :D